# Sort results of search by regex in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting

So, there's a web-server that has a number of methods which are used for autocompleting input fields on the client. Methods take a string and scan a specific property of mongodb collection using regexp.

Pretty common stuff, right? But here's a problem - these methods need to sort results based on how close the searched string is to the start of the result string. Like if I searched for countries and typed "ru", "Russia" should come before "Peru".

I don't see how I can sort results like this without performing multiple searches. Now I can only think of something like this

```
const limit = 20;
const resultsStartOfLine = db.countries.find({name: /^ru/i})
.limit(limit)
.toArray();

const resultsRest = db.countries.find({
    name: /ru/i,
    _id: {$nin: _.map(resultsStartOfLine, '_id')}
})
.limit(limit - resultsStartOfLine.length)
.toArray();
```

I know, that Mongo can't do this kind of sort by default, but maybe there's better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've learned search by regex is usually a bad practice because it doesn't utilize indexes and as a result is pretty slow.
So I created an index for full-text search and sort results by weights.